# How to find out the index of the control in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to remove all controls from a row with the method RemoveAt(Int32 index), but i can't understand which index have any control.

I thought controls in TableLayoutPanel are placed like in table: in a row, beginning from the first column and going to the last., then we go the next row and make the same. So i thought that index of every control can be calculated:
`selectedRow * RowCount + selectedColumn`
But I got this method is incorrect, so I try to find out how to get the index of a control.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep track of the controls separately somewhere?

Comment: Do you know which Control you want to remove or the Cell position where it's located? If you want to actually remove a Control, call `Dispose()` on it, don't use `Controls.RemoveAt()` (e.g. `[TableLayoutPanel].GetControlFromPosition(1, 1).Dispose();`), unless your Controls are part of a collection of Controls that you're managing.

Comment: @Jimi, It is supposed to have a button, which has On_Click() event. And when it occurs, all controls, located in the same row with this button, should be removed

Comment: You could then use `var row = [TableLayoutPanel].GetRow(sender as Control)` (using `sender` if `On_Click()` is the handler method of the `Click` event), then loop the Columns of the same Row, call `GetControlFromPosition()` as described and `Dispose()` of those Controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what Jimi is talking about:

```
private void allButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    int row = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(btn);
    for(int i=0; i<tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(i, row).Dispose();

        // or, if you need to keep those controls for later use
        Control ctl = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(i, row);
        // ...store each "ctl" somewhere...
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(ctl);
    }
}
```